# Finding the vectors of a quadrilateral.

Tags: vectors

The following diagram shows quadrilateral $ABCD$, with vector $AD$ = vector $BC$, vector $AB$ = (3,1), and vector $AC$ (4,4).
[image: diagram]

a. Find vector $BC$.

I am not very sure how you can find this vector based on the others. Would it be (3,4)? Using the x in $AB$ and y in $AC$.

b. Show that vector $BD$ = (-2,2).

If we found vector BC, couldn’t you just go left (on the x axis) until you get to -2?

c. Show that vectors $BD$ and $AC$ are perpendicular.

For this, don’t you multiply them together and add and if it equals 0, then it’s perpendicular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \vec{BC} = \vec{BA}+ \vec{AC}=-\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}
\\=-(3,1)+(4,4)=(1,3)$$

$$\vec{BD} =  \vec{BA}+\vec{AD}=-\vec{AB}+\vec{BC}
\\=-(3,1)+(1,3)=(-2,2)$$

vectors are perpendicular if their dot product equals zero
$$ \vec{BD} \cdot \vec{AC}  =(-2,2)\cdot(4,4) 
\\= (-2)(4)+(2)(4)=0  $$